# return Column1 if all values in Column2 are a specific value

Tags: sql-server

Trying to create a query that will look at all rows with the same value in column 1, then return the value in column1 IF the value in column2 is a specific value.

Example

If this is my table:

```
111 | X

111 | X

111 | X

222 | X

222 | Y

333 | X

333 | X
```

And I want to find and return any values in column 1 that have an X in column 2 in all rows, I expect the result to be:

```
111

333
```

Since all instances of 1111 and 3333 have an X in column2

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

haven't tested on real db, but this should do a trick:

```
select column1
from table
group by column1
having count(distinct column2)=1 and min(column2) = 'X'
```

Comment: Looks like this one is returning what I need!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1 
FROM   dbo.table1 t1 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM   dbo.table1 t2 
                  WHERE  t1.col1 = t2.col1 
                    AND  t2.col2 <> 'X')
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dded7/3/0)</kbd>